# Where is data coming from Tilevector or mapstyle

Tags: vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js, fields-attributes

I'm struggling to use the data that's in a vector tileset source (PortalsWithOrderNr)
I commented out the add.source and add.layer but when I click on a portal I get most of the data that's in the tileset "PortalsWithOrderNr" but not all.
Therefore I think I'm getting the data from the map itself.

How do I work with the data that's in the tileset?

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pedestrian foot traffic at intersections</title>
  <script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.43.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://www.mapbox.com/base/latest/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div id="map" class="mapboxgl-map"><div class="mapboxgl-missing-css">Missing Mapbox GL JS CSS</div><div class="mapboxgl-canvas-container mapboxgl-interactive mapboxgl-touch-drag-pan mapboxgl-touch-zoom-rotate"><canvas class="mapboxgl-canvas" tabindex="0" aria-label="Map" width="960" height="1107" style="position: absolute; width: 768px; height: 886px;"></canvas></div><div class="mapboxgl-control-container"><div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-top-left"></div><div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-top-right"><div class="mapboxgl-ctrl mapboxgl-ctrl-group"><button class="mapboxgl-ctrl-icon mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-in" type="button" aria-label="Zoom In"></button><button class="mapboxgl-ctrl-icon mapboxgl-ctrl-zoom-out" type="button" aria-label="Zoom Out"></button><button class="mapboxgl-ctrl-icon mapboxgl-ctrl-compass" type="button" aria-label="Reset North"><span class="mapboxgl-ctrl-compass-arrow" style="transform: rotate(0deg);"></span></button></div></div><div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-bottom-left"><div class="mapboxgl-ctrl" style="display: block;"><a class="mapboxgl-ctrl-logo" target="_blank" href="https://www.mapbox.com/" aria-label="Mapbox logo"></a></div></div><div class="mapboxgl-ctrl-bottom-right"><div class="mapboxgl-ctrl mapboxgl-ctrl-attrib"><a href="https://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">© Mapbox</a> <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/about/" target="_blank">© OpenStreetMap</a> <a class="mapbox-improve-map" href="https://www.mapbox.com/feedback/?owner=mapbox&amp;id=dark-v9&amp;access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZXhhbXBsZXMiLCJhIjoiY2lqbmpqazdlMDBsdnRva284cWd3bm11byJ9.V6Hg2oYJwMAxeoR9GEzkAA" target="_blank">Improve this map</a></div></div></div></div>
  <!-- style the legend !-->
  <!-- add html elements to the legend !-->
  <div id="legend" class="legend">
    <h4>Pedestrian Traffic</h4>
  <div><span style="width:7.153982198254619px;height:7.153982198254619px;margin: 0 6.4230089008726905px"></span><p>6923</p></div><div><span style="width:10.365486648690965px;height:10.365486648690965px;margin: 0 4.817256675654518px"></span><p>13846</p></div><div><span style="width:13.57699109912731px;height:13.57699109912731px;margin: 0 3.211504450436345px"></span><p>20769</p></div><div><span style="width:16.788495549563656px;height:16.788495549563656px;margin: 0 1.605752225218172px"></span><p>27692</p></div><div><span style="width:20px;height:20px;margin: 0 0px"></span><p>34615</p></div></div>
</head>
  <style>
  #map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  #locations {
    position: absolute;
  }

  .legend {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    bottom: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .legend h4 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
  }

  .legend p {
    margin-left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
  }

  .legend div {
    position:relative;
  }

  .legend div span {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:#D49A66;
  }

  .mapboxgl-popup {
    max-width: 400px;
    font: 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  </style>


<body>
  <script>
  //Put your Mapbox Public Access token here
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZm9yc3N1eCIsImEiOiJjaXNsZm5ld2UwMDZiMm5wa21mZTJtdTA1In0.kZRfmUVy1udXUB3kKUChrQ';

  //Load a new map in the 'map' HTML div
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/forssux/cjbcu8e5g8ij62sldbwwosr89',
     center: [4.404347,51.218568],
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 4,
    zoom: 17
});

  // Store an array of quantiles
  var max = 34615;
  var fifth = 34615 / 5;
  var quantiles = [];
  for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var quantile = (i + 1) * fifth;
    quantiles.push(quantile);
  }

  //Load the vector tile source from our Mapbox Pedestrian traffic example
 /* map.on('load', function() {
    //Add the circle layer to the map
        map.addSource('PortalsWithOrderNr', {
        type: 'vector',
          url: 'mapbox://forssux.cjbcsiw4o15vr2rpbk37848h5-562bk'
    });
   map.addLayer({
      'id': 'PortalName',
      'type': 'symbol',
      'source': {
          type: 'vector',
       url: 'mapbox://forssux.cjbcsiw4o15vr2rpbk37848h5-562bk'
      },
      //name of tilesets
      'source-layer': 'PortalsWithOrderNr',
     'layout': {
            'visibility': 'visible',
           'line-join': 'round',
            'line-cap': 'round'
       },
        'paint': {
            'line-color': '#877b59',
            'line-width': 1
        }
    });
  });*/

    // By default, exponential property functions have a base of 1.
    // Exponential functions with a base of 1 are linear.
    // The relationship between the radius of any point and the number of pedestrians is:
    // radius = rateOfChange * numberOfPedestrians + radiusAtZero

    // When a click event occurs near a place, open a popup at the location of
    // the feature, with description HTML from its properties.
    map.on('click', function(e) {
      var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: ['Portals']//,
    //  layers: ['MissionArea']
      });

      if (!features.length) {
        return;
      }

      var feature = features[0];

      // Populate the popup and set its coordinates
      // based on the feature found.
      var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup()
        .setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
        .setHTML('<div id="popup" class="popup" style="z-index: 10;"> <h5> Detail: </h5>' +
          '<ul class="list-group">' +
          '<li class="list-group-item"> Mission Name: ' + feature.properties['MissionArea'] + " </li>" +
          '<li class="list-group-item"> Portal Name: ' + feature.properties['PortalName'] + " </li>" +
          '<li class="list-group-item"> Portal Nr in Mission: ' + feature.properties['OrderInMission'] + " </li>" +
           '<li class="list-group-item"> Portal URL: ' + feature.properties['Portal URL'] + " </li>" +
          '<li class="list-group-item"> Mission Nummer: ' + feature.properties['MissionNr'] + " </li>" +
          '</ul> </div>')
        .addTo(map);
    });

    // Use the same approach as above to indicate that the symbols are clickable
    // by changing the cursor style to 'pointer'.
    map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
      var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
        layers: ['Portals']
      });
      map.getCanvas().style.cursor = (features.length) ? 'pointer' : '';
    });
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in the internal workings of MapBox but yes, the data that is being displayed is defined and being retrieved from the MapBox style.

In the [MapBox style there is a place to define data sources](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#root-sources).  You can view all the data sources at `map.style.sourceCaches.composite._source.vectorLayers`.  There are actually quite a few data sources included in the style you have chosen.  The last `vectorLayer`, index 25, also known as `PortalsWithOrderNr`, is the one that contains the information about the landmarks.  If you inspect the `map.style.sourceCaches.composite._source.vectorLayers[25].fields` object you can see all the fields that this data source has in it, and you can access.

Which is:

```
MissionArea:"String"
MissionName:"String"
MissionNr:"String"
OrderInMission:"String"
Portal URL:"String"
PortalName:"String"
```

Digging around you may see references to `MissionAreas`, `MissionName`, and `Portals`.  These are the actual stylised layers displayed on the map, derived from the data source known as `PortalsWithOrderNr`.  You can view these at the object: `map.style.sourceCaches.composite.style._layers`.

If you read the [page on the subsection about layers in the style definition](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec#root-layers), it will specify that they are rendered in order.  This will matter in a second.

This all together gives you a 'style' with data in one package.  This allows the artist to create a style that depends on a value from the field from the data sources, or in your example provide some baseline information without having to add external data sources.

---

How to access all that information is simply just adjusting the code you have provided.

Looking at the [documentation for `queryRenderedFeatures`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures) we can see the second parameter filters out any features not in that layer.  And if the second parameter is undefined then it will search all layers.

If we comment out line 132.

```
//layers: ['Portals']//,
```

The function will return an array of all features from all layers under the pointer when clicked.

Before this line (line 140):

```
var feature = features[0];
```

Place this code:

```
console.log(features)
```

Reload and click anywhere on the map and you will see that the console logs all features from all *rendered* layers found under your mouse click.

The popup is currently using field returned from the `feature` object that is defined on line 140.  It selects the first object from the array return by `queryRenderedFeatures`.

It appears that the order the layers are returned by `queryRenderedFeatures` is the order in which they are defined in `map.style.sourceCaches.composite.style._layers` as described in the first section.  It would be best to walk along the array `features` and find the desired layer by a name or id.

By making to changes to the code you now can access all data from all the layers in the style.

---

Another note, more of a code style and convention.  You should move any of the structural code on line 9 - 14 to below the `body` tag but before your `script` tag.  It will behave the same, but you might have undefined behaviour if you mix non-metadata into your `head` section.

Might line break your code block too, makes it easier to read.

And lint your code, sometimes you can catch bugs before they show up in runtime.

---

If you are curious, I believe the data is actually pulled from the tiles cached from the server which seem to be stored at `map.style.sourceCaches.composite._tiles`.  The actually tiles have a long number sequence, but within that object you can drill a bit further to `map.style.sourceCaches.composite._tiles[*some index #*].featureIndex.vtLayers.PortalsWithOrderNr` and find the arrays: `_features`, `_keys` and `_values`.  This seems to be the feature data found within the tile cached, which is then parsed returned via `queryRenderedFeatures`.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for this elaborate answer, it gave me a lot of insights.
Indeed I find all the info necessary.
However why can't I get the info from the vector tile source itself, its smaller.
I thought that the lines which are commented out would do the trick lines (98-125)
But I wish to thank you for your fine answer, have happy holidays